# Shortcode to show the footer

Tags: php, wordpress

how can I create a shortcode (or something similar) to show the footer in somewhere on a page?

I tried with this but no results...

```
function show_footer() {
    return get_footer();
}
add_shortcode( 'show_f', 'show_footer' );
```

or this...

```
function show_footer() {
    get_footer();
}
add_shortcode( 'show_f', 'show_footer' );
```

any idea?

many thanks

Comment: Put this question at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/, there you'll get more specialized answers.

Comment: per the docs (https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Output) you probably need to wrap with `ob_start(); ... return ob_get_clean();`

Comment: Think your looking for a Sidebar. Search for register and display sidebar